# Is there a way to evaluate an AngularJS expression in the template just once (ie. without data-binding)?

Tags: angularjs

It's probably the best to illustrate my question with an example.

Here is a template snippet:

```
<div class="title">{{action}} Location</div>
```

Double curly markup tells AngularJS to evaluate `action` against the current scope **AND** to create a data-binding to `action`.

Is there a way to tell AngularJS to evaluate `action` once and be done (ie. I don't need the data-binding/watch)?

Comment: Downvoted without a reason? Seriously, I think SO should force people to leave their reasons when they downvote a posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found [**Pasvaz's bindonce module**](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce), another solution that suits better for my need, from the Angular mailing list.

**UPDATE 10/27/2014:** Starting from v1.3, AngularJS core supports [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

Answer (score 4):

I cannot find the direct support of `interporate once` feature in Angular.
But you can easily work around it by using separate variable which gets
copied from `action` once and never changes afterwards.

In your controller:

```
$scope.action0 = action;
```

in your template:

```
<div class="title">{{action0}} Location</div>
```

**EDIT** : Another way is to define a directive which interpolates once
and leave it alone.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Ul1QgqhNH0bqK2af2Jo?p=preview

js:

```
app.directive('staticBind', function(){
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.text( scope[ attrs.staticBind ]);
  };
});
```

template:

```
<span static-bind="variable"></span>
```

Comment: My intention is to save some resources by avoiding the watch automatically created on `action`. Whenever double curly markup, `{{expression}}`, is used, AngularJS automatically creates a watch on whatever the expression is defined in the markup, and this is what I want to avoid. Your solution, therefore, does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I want to evaluate the expression but i dont want to display it. so i found one solution, just put your expression that you want to evaluate in ng-hide div and set ng-hide to false like

```
<div ng-hide="true">{{your expression here}}</div>
```

it will execute the expression without displaying the content

Answer (score 0):

Use angular.copy when you set the scope to be used in that template. Angular wont watch a var set to a copy.  angular.copy is used to store the value of the current value of a watchExpression for later comparison.

Comment: Care to elaborate on your solution? Perhaps a quick demo using jsFiddle or plunker.

Comment: this is definitely not working. Try running your demo code on your local machine and inspect `$('div').eq(0).scope().$$watchers`, you can see there are two watchers, one for each `ng-repeat`. I still don't understand your point.

Comment: My use case:
i have a list of users, i get the user list, and copy it from scope to build the list in the UI, the scope i copied it from is used on the right side of list, an editable detail view of each record, that scope can be edited now without affecting the lets say Scope.user.name on the left, when the user updates the form and the post is successful, i'll push the changes to the scope on the left, as clicking on that user name sets the scope on the right, but they are decoupled so that user names aren't changing if the user is changing the name on the right.

Comment: I'll work on a better example.  Sorry if this doesn't match your goal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VLQfz/2/ is working now, wierd.

Point is if you set $scope.staticItems equal to $scope.items, then you still have dual bindings.  Using angular.copy($scope.items) gives you one way binding, which I thought you were asking for.  My bad.

Comment: Your second demo still has two watchers in the scope, just like your first demo. I forked your second demo ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/CG5dj/)) and added another button, which would add item to the static item list. Upon clicking the new button, the static list gets updated in the view. That's a proof showing there's a binding/watcher on the so-called static list, which truly isn't "static" at all. You might wonder where did the binding come from for the "static list". It was done by ngRepeat. You can always look into Angular's source code to learn more.

Comment: Those watchers are created by the ng-repeat directive.  Your question is asking about the var associated with the template.  In your template, you have action as a scope variable.  Using angular.copy on a scope variable does not create a new watcher for the var and it will not be updated when the item it was copied from gets updated.  So using it with the template example you provided for action creates no new watcher.  I was demonstrating the decoupling with ng-repeat, but it seems to have confused the issue.

Comment: Here's your template in the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/VLQfz/5/

If i'm wrong again, which totally happens all the time, I'll be a gentleman and remove my answer, just be constructive in your feedback.

Comment: The link is a little hard to see in my previous comment. Here you are again, [http://jsfiddle.net/CG5dj/](http://jsfiddle.net/CG5dj/). I'm all for being constructive in this community. That's why I appreciate your help and have been spending time evaluating your solution and providing you with my feedback, rather than down voting. I was just suggesting you to remove your solution, if you agree that it doesn't respond to my question. Perhaps I should have worded my comment better. Sorry if my poor use of words have offended you. That was not my intention.